# CodeIgniter - Using FlashData WITH Sessions Stored in database

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

My configuration on CI is pretty standard.

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 2000;
```

I don't use expire because I am testing the system, I know it's not good practice. I use a high sess_time_to_update because of AJAX requests destroying the session (a CI bug).

I now have a new bug which I believe has to do with my code but I'm not sure how to fix it.

I've been storing my sessions in a database using one database connection. The flashdata to display error messages has been working perfectly.. until recently. Now the flashdata wont set when I introduced a second database connection.

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'emp';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

$db['dil']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['dil']['username'] = 'root';
$db['dil']['password'] = '';
$db['dil']['database'] = 'dil';
$db['dil']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['dil']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['dil']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['dil']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['dil']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['dil']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['dil']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['dil']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['dil']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['dil']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['dil']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

After I set my flash data I display it with var_dump and print_r and it prints a boolean: false. When I don't use a second connection it works fine. Any ideas? Some people say to not store sessions in DB but I need to for security.

**Update:** I that assumed the set_flashdata didnt insert it into the database so I checked to be sure and that is the problem. set_flashdata is not inserting the flash data. Other pages with two connections works fine (the notifications) just this page isnt.

**Update 2:** When I set the flashdata and exit; right after i look in the database and there is a message: "You need to login to see this page". This is set when someone isnt logged in. Hm.. definitely something weird going on...

**Update 3:** after using the log_message( in the SESS_WRITE( function in the Core/libraries/session file I see that it sets the message correctly but then there is an extra refresh some how...

```
ERROR - 2012-11-23 15:38:39 --> "logged_in";b:1;}
ERROR - 2012-11-23 15:38:39 -->"logged_in";b:1;s:22:"flash:new:notification";a:2:{s:4:"type";s:7:"success";s:7:"message";s:31:"Image was updated successfully.";}}
```

**SOLVED**
Thanks to mohan.gade I've found a solution.

When working with multiple databases with the way I set mine up (default, db1, db2 etc..) when you load a new database into a variable when you autoload the default database it resets the $this->db.

```
$this->db1 = $this->load->database('db1', TRUE);
```

So the fix...although not fun...is to load all databases manually when working with multiple connections.

```
$this->db = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
$this->db1 = $this->load->database('db1', TRUE);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How doyou make database connection ? Is config/autoload library contains 'database' ? then remove it . do the database conncetion manually.
If you need to connect to more than one database simultaneously you can do so as follows:
       $emp = $this->load->database('emp', TRUE);
       $dil = $this->load->database('dil', TRUE);
       And access the database functions following way
       $emp->query();
       insted of regular method $this->db->query()
       for more details go to the http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html

Comment: After days of debugging this seems to be the issue. I will mark this as answered and give a brief solution in my question at the bottom. Thank you so much.