# CodeIgniter 3 - flashdata() always returns null after a page reload

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Migrating from CodeIgniter2 to CI3. PHP 8.2

I've confirmed that there are not multiple requests, by looking at network traffic. There are only 4 other files loaded from the same server, and those are favicon, two svg files, and a javascript script, none of which go through CI. Also, if multiple requests were causing this, that would have happened in the old CI2 system as well, but that's working fine.

Calling `set_flashdata()` sets the appropriate record in the session_ci3 table. Reloading the page removes the flashdata from the record, as expected.

Calling `flashdata()` returns the correct value if called immediately after `set_flashdata()`.

```
$mytestmessage = $this->session->flashdata('mytestmessage');
echo "Old testmessage: $mytestmessage";
$this->session->set_flashdata('mytestmessage', 'THIS IS A TEST FLASHDATA MESSAGE');
$mytestmessage = $this->session->flashdata('mytestmessage');
echo "New testmessage: $mytestmessage";
```

The output of running the above code multiple times is always: "Old testmessage: New testmessage: THIS IS A TEST FLASHDATA MESSAGE"

Expected output is "Old testmessage: THIS IS A TEST FLASHDATA MESSAGENew testmessage: THIS IS A TEST FLASHDATA MESSAGE"

The question was not answered in the following:

- [CodeIgniter 3 redirect function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33686117/2407309)
- [codeigniter flashdata not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32065825/2407309)
- [Why flashdata is not working in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50289164/2407309)
- [CodeIgniter session set_flashdata not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27773066/2407309)
- [CodeIgniter - Using FlashData WITH Sessions Stored in database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13536101/2407309)

Comment: what's your CI version?

Comment: Hi, yes, I read that, but what specific CI 3.x version are you using?

Comment: @Vickel version 3.1.13

Comment: OK, that's the most recent one... I've read in the CI forum, that there are problems with flashdata https://forum.codeigniter.com/showthread.php?tid=79136&pid=386530#pid386530. No idea if that ever was fixed. In the worse case use normal $_SESSION and unset it manually wherever needed (not a good solution, hence a comment)

Answer (score 1):

to start with, [flashdata](https://%09https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=flashdata#CI_Session::flashdata) itself is in CI3.x already a legacy method, for backwards compatibility only:

> This is a legacy method kept only for backwards compatibility with
> older applications. You should directly access $_SESSION instead.

**TL; TD;**

using php 8.1.2 flashdata works flawless

using php 8.2.9 older sites may throw deprecation warnings, if application environment is set to "development"; Those warnings will disable the flow of flashdata

You can resolve this by setting the application environment in the root index.php to "testing" or "production".
Then no deprecation warnings are thrown, flashdata works as designed.

**looking deeper:**

until php8.1, no deprecation warnings for creation of dynamic property are thrown

with php 8.2 those warnings are shown like

> Message: [Creation of dynamic property ... is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74879495/2275490)

with future php 9.x be aware that those deprecation warnings will be effectively an error, see [PHP RFC: Deprecate dynamic properties](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_dynamic_properties), with a solution provided by the built-in attribute called `AllowDynamicProperties`.

now if you look closer into CI's system/core you'll find the culprit in it's `Exceptions.php` function `show_php_error(...)`. It has an `include()`
which carries out a new request and hence 'kills' your flashdata.

this function is not called (for deprecation warnings), when environment is set to "testing" or "production" and flashdata continues seamless.

Comment: Confirmed that ENVIRONMENT is already set to 'production', and that show_php_error() is not being called, nor are show_exception() nor show_error()

Comment: I've tested it with 2 functions in my main_controller: test0 and test1. in test0 I set the flashdata, in test1 I get the flashdata, both work correctly, I see the flashdata data in test1. Refreshening test1 eliminates the flashdata, also correct. I'm typing those functions in url (mydomain/test0 and then mydomain/test1). I have set php 8.2.9. and CI 3.1.13

Answer (score -1):

flashdata not longer supported in newer version of php you shuold replace flashdata with tempdata

```
$mytestmessage = $this->session->tempdata('mytestmessage');
echo "Old testmessage: $mytestmessage";
$this->session->set_tempdata('mytestmessage', 'THIS IS A TEST FLASHDATA MESSAGE', 5);
$mytestmessage = $this->session->tempdata('mytestmessage');
echo "New testmessage: $mytestmessage";
```

More Details:
[CodeIgniter Session Library](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=tempdata)

Comment: That documentation states "CodeIgniter supports “flashdata”, or session data that will only be available for the next request, and is then automatically cleared."

Comment: Yes codeigniter supports flashdata but if want to run ci3 in php8 or later then php8 doesn't allow flashdata.  Don't worry There is another ci function  tempdata,  set_tempdata

Comment: If you run your code in php7 then flashdata works great but in php8 or later you shuold alternative tempdata