# Moved my CodeIgniter site from GoDaddy to Bluehost and now I can't make it show up on my browser

Tags: codeigniter, web-hosting

I have a functioning website that's created in CodeIgniter on my GoDaddy, it's version 3.0 and can only run in php5.6 - Since Godaddy is upgrading my server and they require php7.2 and above, I need to move it somewhere else as I don't want to mess up anything on it.

Now after transferring, it keeps showing the index.html file when I open it in my browser which basically just contains "Under Maintenance" text.

I did the following when I moved the site:

1. Copied files from GoDaddy cPanel and transferred it to cPanel in Bluehost
2. Copied database from GoDaddy and moved it to Bluehost
3. Updated the config.php file and added the database credentials that is in Bluehost

When I opened the site, it shows the index.html file with the "Under Maintenance" text. I tried renaming the index.html file to ensure that only the index.php is loaded. But when I opened it in my browser it shows 404 Not Found error. I tried opening other pages as well and it still shows 404.

I already asked Bluehost support but everyone I talked to seems to be only knowledgeable with Wordpress. Basically they were not able to help me out.

Does anyone here have the same problem or encountered the same situation and got it fixed?

Comment: when you move a website from one (shared) server to another you need to update your DNS settings. have you done that? Also you'll need to wait some time (some say up to 24h ) for propagation of those settings. BTW.: you can use CI 3.x even with current php 8.2. You may need to fix some deprecation warnings and eventually replace some php functions.

Comment: hi thanks for replying, I'm using bluehost's temporary domain and wanted to make sure that the site is working on that temp domain before I transfer the DNS. The site is still live and I can't risk it going offline because its an important part of our process and it needs to be online.

Comment: well since you can use CI3.x with php 8.2.; (check an answer of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77559496/codeigniter-3-flashdata-always-returns-null-after-a-page-reload/77603321#77603321)) I wouldn't bother to change server (that if you are pleased with godaddy)

Comment: thank you! I will check your suggestion.